# Adding style to ComboBoxItem through ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Below is the code with the error.

When I do ComboBox directly instead of ItemsControl it's ok.

But the question is how to do it through ItemsControl? I have to use this as WPF in the case of ComboBox mindlessly adds an empty ComboBox when I have nothing added (added elements are dynamically). I can not get rid of him. ItemsControl is added as expected, i.e. only when I add it dynamically.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorItemsY}">
    <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
    </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

ConnectorItemsY -> Collections of ComboBox

EDIT:

The code below rotates as I like but uses ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorItemsY}">
    <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
    </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

[image]
[image]

The left picture is rotated ComboBox. On the right view after clicking on it with the content rotated. I want it to work without using the ComboBox xaml file only with the help of ItemsControl.

Comment: What error? Without screenshot it's hard to tell what is happening and what you want instead.

Comment: I want to rotate items

Comment: I still don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a `ComboBox` or not :-D? And if not, how should the result look like, could you draw an example mockup?

Comment: ComboBox will be added in the code. When I use the name directly like in `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorItemsY}">` it's just when I run the WPF application that I get an empty ComboBox, although it can not be at the beginning. It should appear when I need it along with the content. At the right moment I get when I call ItemsControl but in this case it does not work its rotation as in the previous case.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the style to `ItemsControl.Resources` for it to  be applied to all `ComboBoxItems` inside:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorItemsY}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
    </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
    <ItemsControl.Items>

    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

A `Style` is not actually a control, so you cannot put it in the XAML tree next to controls like this. It is just a "blueprint" that sets some properties of any control of the given type in the XAML tree below the style and must be put into a `Resources` collection of a control. In this case you are targeting `ComboBoxItem` which means that all items in `ComboBox` controls inside `ItemsControl.Items` should have your style applied.

You can also name the `Style` using `x:Key` and then manually apply it wherever you see fit using `Style="{StaticResource KeyOfTheStyle}"`

Comment: The code above does not rotate the content. I want to rotate an angle Container Items

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `ComboBoxItem` style to be applied to all `ComboBoxItem` elements in the `ConnectorItemsY` source collection, you should simply change `<ItemsControl.Items>` to `<ItemsControl.Resources>`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorItemsY}">
    <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
    </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you want to rotate the items "back", you should also specify an angle of `-270`:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-270" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I want to turn the entire ContainerItems. When I add a style to `<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>` and replace it with ComboBox it works but I need to have ItemsControl.

Comment: Replace -270 with 0 or whatever angel you want to rotate the item with. Or what do you mean? What is "ContainerItems"?

Comment: You are rotating the ItemsControl itself by 270 degrees.

Comment: Change the Angle in the Style to 180 or 360? Or explain exaclty what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "containeritems" means the container of all the items.

In which case you could rotate the itemspresenter rather than the individual items.
Quick experiment:

```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
        </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}"
                          >
                    <ComboBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ItemsPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-270" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.Resources>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

and my viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<object>
    {
      new {Name="Item 1", SubItems= new List<int>{11,22,33,44 } },
      new {Name="Item 2", SubItems= new List<int>{11,22,33,44 } },
      new {Name="Item 3", SubItems= new List<int>{11,22,33,44 } },
    };
```

When I drop down a combo (sideways), the list appears vertically.